# System.__ComObject instead of database value

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am fairly new to asp and I have been trying to get an aspx page to pull data from a database. However instead of displaying the values, I get `System.__ComObject` down the page. here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Form to database - showing records</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 

    Dim connection, recordset, prod, area, number
    Dim sSQL, sConnString


    prod = Request.Form("product")
    area = Request.Form("Area")
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & area & " " & prod & "]"


    connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


    sConnString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
     "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("SPC Data.mdb")

     connection.Open(sConnString)

    recordset.Open(sSQL, connection)

    'Test to see if the code will pull any number at all
    number = recordset("Batch ID").ToString
    Response.Write("Number =" & number & "<br/>")

recordset.Close
    recordset = Nothing
connection.Close
    connection = Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I have researched this topic quite a bit, but have yet to find a way to fix my problem. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your query returns a recordset instead of a single record, so you should iterate it. It should be something like this:

```
For i = 0 To recordset.Fields.Count -1
 Response.Write "Field Name: " & RS.Fields(i).Name & "<br>"
 Response.Write "Field Value: " & RS(i) & "<br>"
```

Next
Fix column names properly.